# Inject httpSession in spring ApplicationListener

Tags: java, spring

I try to get sessionId inside applicationListener impl. It throws NULLPointerException in session.getId(). I wonder why it got exception. The session is created but cannot access other attributes. Below is my code.

```
    @Component
    public class MyEventListener implements ApplicationListener<MyEvent> {

    @Autowired
      HttpSession session;

     @Override
      public void onApplicationEvent(final QuotePricingEvent quoteEvent) {

        LOGGER.error("Session id: {}, userid: {}", session.getId());
    }
}
```

Edit

```
@Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(RequestContextListener.class);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a full stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

Please ensure that you have registered a `RequestContextListener` in your `web.xml` so that Spring can inject the current `HTTPSession`.

```
<listener>  
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>  
</listener>
```

Comment: i added RequestContextListener in AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer impl.